# How to strip trailing URL characters in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm hoping someone can help with this one. I run a forum written in Perl, and the forum does something to URLs that is causing search engines to create duplicates.

I'm thinking that the best way of handling this is to sort it at the htaccess level.

As an example, the following 4 URLs all go to the same page, but search engines are seeing one entry with three duplicates:

```
http://www.domain.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890
http://www.domain.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890/2
http://www.domain.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890/19
http://www.domain.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890/22
```

I'm looking get htaccess to redirect anything that has a forward-slash somewhere in the last three characters, to a URL that has the slash and trailing numbers removed. Using the above example:

```
Redirect 301 /forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890/2 to /forum/YaBB.pl?num=1234567890
```

Alternatively, to re-write URLs from that subdomain to strip "/n" and "/nn"

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your only concern is SEO .. then use `<link rel="canonical"` -- this was specifically designed for such purposes: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394 ; http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=771adc6e72eff5b7&hl=en ; http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: That would be my preference too. I would need to add something to the perl that would dynamically generate the meta tag based on the URL of the forum message minus the trailing characters. Dunno how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=([0-9]+)/[0-9]+$ cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=$1 [R=302,L]
```

This should work, but let me know if it doesn't :) Also if it works, change the 'R=302' to 'R=301'

Comment: Hi Tom,

Thanks for that, but doesn't appear to work.

I gave you an incorrect URL - missed the cgi-bin.

Changed code to 

`RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/forum/YaBB\.pl?num=([0-9]+)/[0-9]+$ cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=$1 [R=302,L]`

but no luck

Example URL: [link](http://www.teadunking.co.uk/cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1164625631/1)

Comment: @steve I have edited my answer to include the cgi-bin folder, but I also noticed I forgot a backslash before the ? in the rewriterule, causing it to not work.

Comment: Thanks Tom. While you were replying, I tried a simple 301 redirect. Looks like the cgi-bin is ignoring the htaccess file completely, as even a simple redirect is being ignored. Might be a server config issue. Will check that before I try anything else

Comment: @Tom, @Steve I'm sorry guys .. but neither `RewriteRule` or `Redirect` directive work with query string that way (`Redirect` cannot match query string at all). @Steve -- you've mentioned that even simple redirect does not work. How simple it was? Please test as simple as possible. Please check with your Hosting company if you have mod_rewrite enabled and RewriteRules can be placed in htaccess file

Comment: How about this?
    `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=([0-9]+)/[0-9]+$`
    `RewriteRule ^YaBB\.pl YaBB.pl?num=%1`

Comment: Hi Tom, Sorry for the delay. Now have rewrite rules enabled on the server, after some help from ISP. Have now tested. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=([0-9]+)/[0-9]+$ RewriteRule ^YaBB\.pl YaBB.pl?num=%1` returns a 500 Internal Server Error, and `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=([0-9]+)/[0-9]+$ cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=$1 [R=302,L]` appears to do nothing. Is there anythging else you can suggest? Many thanks

Comment: @Steve Check your Apache error log for exact message for 500 error.

Comment: This doesn't work `RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/forum/test1.pl$ cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl` so I assume mod_rewrite and/or Rewrite rules not enables - one for the ISP as suggested

Comment: @LazyOne - The {QUERY_STRING} code that shows 500 has the following in the log: "var/www/vhosts/teadunking.co.uk/cgi-bin/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://www.teadunking.co.uk/ "

Comment: I also see a couple of occurences of this message in the log: "Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=(\d+)/
RewriteRule ^(cgi-bin/forum/YaBB\.pl)$ /$1?num=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Tested on local Apache installation -- works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sadly, no joy. It's live, but not doing anything to [link](http://www.teadunking.co.uk/cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1311744428/1). Suspecting it's an ISP issue, and I've raised a support request to get them to confrm whether rewrite works.

Comment: @Steve Where did you put this? In .htaccess file in website root folder (e.g. `http://www.example.com/.htaccess`) ... or somewhere else?

Comment: Didn't work in the root. As advised by the ISP, it's in the cgi-bin folder (sits outside httpdocs). Standard Redirect 301s working OK in htaccess, just no re-write

Comment: @Steve Well... IF .htaccess is in `/cgi-bin/` folder .. then you should **remove** `cgi-bin/` part from RewriteRule pattern (although, if it's "outside httpdocs" .. then I'm not sure about all of this).